# How to get speech recognition results from Google's "Voice Actions"?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Trying to use Google's "Voice Actions" in my app via `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`. According to documentation, I should be able to get the speech recognition results via `RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS`. It seems `onActivityResult()` in the code below is called immediately after `startActivityForResult()` and the results is not OK yet. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
int VOICE_ACTIONS_CODE = 1234 ;
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH) ;
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM) ;
startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_ACTIONS_CODE) ;

. . .

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == VOICE_ACTIONS_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS) ;
            // The following should print speech recog. results
            Log.w("Results from Voice Actions:", result.get(0)) ;
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data) ;
}
```

Comment: I answered without asking what do you really want to do, cause the WEB_SEARCH mode is for a pretty specific functionality. Do you want to perform a web search with the result of the recognition?

Comment: @mdelolmo Yes, but that is only one functionality of `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`. See [Voice Actions](http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/) for more. And besides launching the "action", I also want to know the speech recognition result yielding to that action.

Answer (score 0):

If the result is not `RESULT_OK` is because for some reason the Intent didn't go well. Do you have an internet connection and the corrsponding permissions in your application manifest?

If not, try adding them.

Btw, if you don't get `RESULT_OK`, what's the value of `resultCode` you get?

@@@@@@@@ EDIT @@@@@@@@

Now I fully understand your question.

The issue is the following, you launch the Intent with action `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` and it never returns a result when, according to the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH), it should. It calls `onActivityResult` just when the "Speak Now" dialog is displayed, it's impossible that it returns any result of the speech recognition.

Nevertheless, it triggers the corresponding action. But I agree with you, the behaviour is not the one described in the docs.

I'm sorry, I just can say it looks like an API's implementation fault.

Comment: The intent goes as expected, but when `onActivityResult()` is called, the intent is not finished yet. At that point, `resultCode` equals "0" or `RESULT_CANCELED`. Btw, when launching with `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH`, I am able to get the speech recognition results in `onActivityResult()`, so there should be no problem with app manifest file.

Comment: @Dusan Does it trigger any `ActivityNotFoundException`? Check the logcat

Comment: No. But there is the following warning: _ActivityManager(142): Activity is launching as a new task, so cancelling activity result_.

Comment: @Dusan, I have tested the same, and it does return `RESULT_CANCELED`, but you are telling me that you can get the speech recognition results, so do I. In my case the prompt with the possible actions with the result is also displayed.  So maybe is just not supposed to return any result, therefore, according to the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) it'll return 0. So, is there an actual problem?

Comment: I was not able to get speech recognition results in `onActivityResult()` when launching `RecognizerIntent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` intent. Have you been able to do that? According to [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_WEB_SEARCH), I should be able to get those results from `EXTRA_RESULTS`.

Comment: Hi @Dusan, if you read my edited answer you will see I think you're totally right...